# Logging Into A Mac using only an iOS Device?

Tags: macos, ios, mac, login, login-screen

If a keyboard becomes non functional, and a replacement is not readily available, or you may wish to login remotely to your Mac from another location perhaps:

What options exist (if any) to login to one's Mac computer using only an iPhone or iPad ?

Comment: It might help to get good answers by being a bit more specific. What kind of real-world problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @patrix Have now added more of an intro.

Comment: @Simon If all you wish to do is unlock your Mac you may also consider http://www.knocktounlock.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the firewall exceptions, there are options such as [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com), which has an [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/logmein/id479229407) and a web client, and is free for the first ten devices you want to manage. The caveat is that you must install an app on the device which you want to access. The iOS app works smoothly over both WiFi and LTE, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

A VNC client like this [VNC Viewer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vnc-viewer/id352019548) would work. You'll have to first enable VNC access on your Mac, however.

For access over the internet (from outside your network), you will probably have to set up some firewall exceptions.